# Deleting an Array of rows and columns

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, if-statement

I've got some reports which have sub-totals littered inbetween them. I need to delete the sub-totals, which is easy enough to condition on (as is in my IF statement).

However, my following code just does not delete the entire row of subtotals.

```
Sub clean_up()
'declare variables
Dim i As Integer
Dim noRows As Integer

'count rows
noRows = Range("B2:B387").Rows.Count

'delete row entries that are duplicates..
For i = 1 To noRows
    If Range("B2").Cells(i + 1, 1) = Range("B2").Cells(i, 1) Then
    Range("B2:G2").Cells(i + 1).Clear


    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I do not understand why the `Range("B2:G2").Cells(i + 1).Clear` of my code is incorrect. Using `Range("B2").Cells(i + 1).Clear` works to delete the first entry in the row, so shouldn't `Range("B2:G2").Cells(i + 1).Clear` delete the entire row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only affecting a single cell because you start with a range (`Range("B2:G2")`) and then tell it to only clear one cell (`.Cells(i + 1)`) of that range (offset 1 row down). Better to start with a single cell and use the [Range.Resize property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) to adjust the number of columns.

```
Range("B2").Cells(i + 1).RESIZE(1, 6).Clear
```

Comment: `Range("B2:G6").Rows(i + 1).Clear` should also do the trick... ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel - I was also thinking of `Range("B2:G6").Offset(i, 0).Clear` but I hadn't tested it to ensure that **i** was the correct offset.

Comment: @DirkReichel - I don't know what error you are referring to. There is nothing wrong with using the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) to  extend outside of a given range whether that range is a single cell of multiple cells.

Comment: Just by phone... you are right. Range.Cells will always offset by the upper left cell of the range... it just looks wrong...